# Asp.net Hyperlink Control NavigateURL property is not working in mywebsite

Tags: asp.net, button, navigation

Website URL:

https://www.tabir.pk/DreamHome.aspx/AMC/Level%201?ShowNav=false

Please login with following details:

Email: abc@abc.com
password: 12345678

When you click on physics blue button it did not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class `pending-briefing` for the anchor is blocking the submission, if you removed it the anchor will be working fine and redirect to the other page normally.